# How can I make the loop increment?

Tags: python, for-loop

For some reason, the value of y wont increment in the loop. I tried using it inside the loop but then I'd have to work backwards, but even then the code didn't work the way it was supposed to.

It's supposed to be 1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4 ...xn

```
def minus(r,y):
    result = 0 
    term = 0
    for _ in range(0,y,+1):
        result =+ term
        term = term + (-r**y) 
        print(term)
        print(f"{r}^{y} = {(r**y)}") #was checking value of y but it remians the same throughout
    return result
r = int(input("Enter root -> "))
y= int(input("Enter range -> "))
print(minus(r,y))
```

Output:

```
Enter root -> 5
Enter range -> 4
-625
5^4 = 625
-1250
5^4 = 625
-1875
5^4 = 625
-2500
5^4 = 625
-1875
```

Comment: `result =+ term` means `result = +term`, you probably want `result += term`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the value of `y` anywhere. Change

```
def minus(r,y):
```

to

```
def minus(r, max_y):
```

and

```
for _ in range(0,y,+1):
```

to

```
for y in range(max_y + 1)
```

As a side note, I believe what you want is `(-r)**i` instead of `(-r**i)`.